# How to hide APPKey when using Github

Tags: swift, github, xcode9

I would like to share my code to Github in Public , but the APPKey needs to be private . How can I just hide APPKey in the file?
iOS Programming , using Swift4 ,Xcode 9

Comment: Please be more specific. Like which programming language are you going to use with?

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1

Generally people will save the key into a file named `secret.key` or something like that and add the file to `.gitignore` so that it is not saved in the git repository.

The program can then read the key from the file at run time.

#### Option 2

You can store the key in an environment variable that is read at runtime. [Here is a blog post by Robin Malhotra describing how to do so with Xcode](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/secret-variables-in-xcode-and-your-ci-for-fun-and-profit-d387a50475d7)

Comment: Perhaps you want to add how can OP import the key into the code using the secret variables? I am not too familiar with Swift and Xcode per se.

Comment: OP updated question. Originally they did not mention a specific language. I do not know Swift either. Maybe someone else can post a more complete answer.